# Covariance and Scala Collections

Tags: list, scala, set, covariance

I'm trying to get my head around the covariance of Scala's collections.  I have the following:

```
abstract class MediaFormat{
    def name:String
    def status:String
}

case class H264_high(status:String="on") extends MediaFormat {
    def name = "h264_high"
}
case class H264_med(status:String="on") extends MediaFormat {
    def name = "h264_med"
}
case class H264_low(status:String="on") extends MediaFormat {
    def name = "h264_low"
}
case class H264_syndication(status:String="off") extends MediaFormat {
    def name = "h264_syndication"
}
```

What I wanted to do was have a set of all of these formats because I need a collection where each format only occurs once, so I tried:

```
object MediaFormat {
    val allFormats:Set[MediaFormat] = Set(H264_high,H264_low)
}
```

This gave me a compile time exception because, as I now understand, Set is invariant.

So I think, well I guess I'll just have to use a List and manage the repeated values myself

but then I try this:

```
object MediaFormat {
    val allFormats:List[MediaFormat] = List(H264_high,H264_low)
}
```

because as I understand it, List *is* covariant, but that still doesn't compile.

Can someone help me understand what I should do to get a collection of my formats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't compile because you are referencing the *companion object* (module), not the case classes! The compile error (which you should have posted) is nothing to do with variance. It *will* work, with `Set` if you do this:

```
val allFormats: Set[MediaFormat] = Set(H264_high(), H264_low())
                                                ^^          ^^
```

Or alternatively;

```
val allFormats = Set[MediaFormat](H264_high(), H264_low())
```

However, it makes no sense for these to be case classes given your description of the problem; I would just make them modules, i.e.

```
case object H264_syndication extends MediaFormat {
  def status = "off"
  def name = "h264_syndication"
}
```

Then your original code will work just fine. Or I would make them vals as follows:

```
case class MediaFormat(status: String, name: String)
val H264_syndication = MediaFormat(status ="off", name = "h264_syndication")
```

I think this would be my preference; I rarely use abstract classes any more to be honest (normally, I am dishonest).

---

*Explanation*: Covariance means the following:

> `G[S] <: G[T]` iff `S <: T`

The fact that `Set` is invariant, means that a `Set[S]` is not a subtype of `Set[T]` (for `S <: T`), but it **does not mean** that such a `Set[T]` may not contain *elements* of type `S`.

Comment: Thanks so much - I'm very glad that I was wrong about the invariance of Set.  This makes things a lot easier!

Comment: @Paul You were not wrong about `Set` invariance. `Set[H264_low]` is not a subtype of `Set[MediaFormat]`. However, since `H264_low` is a subtype of `MediaFormat`, you can put it inside a `Set[MediaFormat]`.

Comment: Daniel - isn't that what my answer says? :-p

Comment: I assume when Paul says "wrong about the invariance of Set" he means wrong about *his understanding of it*

Comment: Yes that is what I meant and thanks for adding the last part about using vals, that definitely makes what I'm doing easier. I had hit upon another problem which your have also now solved.